# Read a part of a string and count how many times it appears below in bash

Tags: string, bash, file, count

I have a file like this:

```
USERID1,USERNAME2,GROUP1,OTHER
USERID2,USERNAME2,GROUP2,OTHER
USERID3,USERNAME3,GROUP1,OTHER
USERID4,USERNAME4,GROUP3,OTHER
```

What I need to do is count how many users are in `GROUP1`, in `GROUP2`, etc.

But the problem is that I don't know the names of those groups. So I need to create a variable each time I find a need group and increment +1 each time I found a group which already has a variable. And all this using bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this using awk:

```
$ awk -F, '{++a[$3]}END{for(i in a)print a[i], "users in group", i}' file 
2 users in group GROUP1
1 users in group GROUP2
1 users in group GROUP3
```

`-F,` sets the input field separator to a comma. The third field is used as the key for the array `a`, so separate counts are kept for each group. Once the file has been processed, the value for each key is reported.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming every user per line is unique and that each of the lines follow the same pattern strictly, you could use something like the following to count how many entries there are for each group:

```
$ sort -t',' -k3 filename | cut -d',' -f3 | uniq -c
   2 GROUP1
   1 GROUP2
   1 GROUP3
```

Or, simply:

```
$ cut -d',' -f3 filename | sort | uniq -c
   2 GROUP1
   1 GROUP2
   1 GROUP3
```